# Custom Command for fetching the custom results from commandline output

Tags: shell, command-line

I need to write a shell script which will fetch the custom results from the command-line output being displayed.

Consider the following scenario:

This is the command and related output.

```
root@devstack:/opt/devstack# /usr/local/bin/neutron subnet-list
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name                | cidr                | allocation_pools                                                              |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3efe15d0-24a4-4618-8034-26345438da41 | private-subnet      | 10.0.0.0/24         | {"start": "10.0.0.2", "end": "10.0.0.254"}                                    |
| 4bf54b31-c14c-493b-92c1-079c65484113 | public-subnet       | 172.24.4.0/24       | {"start": "172.24.4.2", "end": "172.24.4.254"}                                |
| 4fbe1ac2-ff40-4efa-8333-2c02be54312e | ipv6-private-subnet | fd6e:78a4:ae52::/64 | {"start": "fd6e:78a4:ae52::2", "end": "fd6e:78a4:ae52:0:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff"} |
| 09b45af3-ef6f-4ad8-a4cb-643b218f0439 | ipv6-public-subnet  | 2001:db8::/64       | {"start": "2001:db8::3", "end": "2001:db8::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff"}              |
|                                      |                     |                     | {"start": "2001:db8::1", "end": "2001:db8::1"}                                |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now What I need is to get the id only for name field having following values:

```
private-subnet
public-subnet
```

I have tried the command as follows for getting only the id with no condition specified:

```
root@devstack:/opt/devstack# /usr/local/bin/neutron subnet-list | awk '{print $2}'

id

4fbe1ac2-ff40-4efa-8333-2c02be54312e
09b45af3-ef6f-4ad8-a4cb-643b218f0439
|
3efe15d0-24a4-4618-8034-26345438da41
4bf54b31-c14c-493b-92c1-079c65484113
```

Some one let me know the value of getting only the "id" where name having the values "private-subnet" and "public-subnet".

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same with the options which available with the neutron subnet-list command.

I can be able to get the results needed as expected.

```
root@devstack:/opt/devstack# /usr/local/bin/neutron subnet-list --field id --name private-subnet
+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| 3efe15d0-24a4-4618-8034-26345438da41 |
+--------------------------------------+
```